# Graph with categorical axis

Tags: stata

I have data with individuals grouped into 30 sites, and each site has a numeric ID. The site size varies quite a bit. I'd like to produce a graph with a vertical axis showing some site-level measure, and the horizontal axis showing the site IDs sorted from largest to smallest. My gut is that I should create a new site ID numbered 1 to 30 with the largest site being 1, etc. But then how could I tell Stata to label tick marks along the horizontal axis using the true site IDs, which would be unordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent a data example, consider some technique:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph bar (mean) price, over(rep78, sort(1)) 
graph bar (mean) price, over(rep78, sort(1) descending)
```

Comment: I think that should do it, since looking into syntax for over it seems I can sort on some other variable. Thanks!